# Handling Large volume of data (5TB) using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have 5 TB of data, it's more than 100 000 CSVs files on a cluster Hadoop.

My first goal is to create a groupements of this CSVs with deleted few columns, add new columns with basic opperations, and add others columns with the informations extract with a `collect()` about the csv. (I know that `collect()` is an action method, but I have no choice because I have my informations at the second row of each CSV).

My issue is when I am starting the handling of a little part of this data, I have errors like heap memory error, or GC error.

I work with Spark 2.2.1 with scala 2.11.12. My cluster have 40 GB of memory, and 48 cores.

My question is: when I handling a little groupement of CSVs and write it in Hadoop, can I clear the GC and the heap memory at my jupyter notebook for continuous automaticly handling without my intervention ?

Thx.

Edit :

```scala
val files = new ListBuffer[String]()

FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://****/"), sc.hadoopConfiguration)
          .listStatus(new Path("/"))
          .foreach( x => files += x.getPath().toString)

val paths = files.toDF("Path")

val index_hdfs = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://****/Index1.parquet")

val join = paths.join(index_hdfs, paths.col("Path") === index_hdfs.col("treated_paths"), "left")

val filter = join.where(col("treated_paths") isNull).select($"Path")

val to_do = filter.limit(50)

val index1 = new ListBuffer[String]()

val df_schema = StructType(
                           List(
                                    StructField("S1", StringType, true),
                                    StructField("S2", StringType, true),

                                    StructField("delta_c_bis", DoubleType, true),
                                    StructField("delta_d_bis", DoubleType, true)                              
                                )
                          )

var bigDf = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], df_schema)

to_do.collect.foreach { path => 
    
                                index1 += path(0).toString
    
                                val tmp_df = spark
                                                .read
                                                .option("header", "true")
                                                .option("delimiter", ";")
                                                .csv(path(0).toString)
                                                .select($"a", $"b", $"c_bis", $"d_bis").repartition(4)
    
                                val tmp_df2 = tmp_df.withColumn("S1", lit(tmp_df.filter($"a" === "S1")
                                                                                .map(r => r.getAs[String](1))
                                                                                .collect()
                                                                                .mkString(" ")))

                                val tmp_df3 = tmp_df2.withColumn("S2", lit(tmp_df.filter($"b" === "S2")
                                                                                .map(r => r.getAs[String](1))
                                                                                .collect()
                                                                                .mkString(" ")))

                               
                                                                                .drop("a")
                                                                                .drop("b")
    
                                val tmp_df4 = tmp_df3.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    
                                val my_window = Window.partitionBy($"S1").orderBy("id")
    
                                
    
                                val tmp_df5 = tmp_df4.withColumn("prec_c_bis", lag($"c_bis", 1).over(my_window))
                                                     .withColumn("prec_d_bis", lag($"d_bis", 1).over(my_window))
                                        
            
                                val tmp_df6 = tmp_df5.withColumn("delta_c_bis", when(isnull($"c_bis"), 0)
                                                                              .otherwise($"c_bis" - $"prec_c_bis"))
    
                                val tmp_df7 = tmp_df6.withColumn("delta_d_bis", when(isnull($"d_bis"), 0)
                                                                              .otherwise($"d_bis" - $"prec_d_bis"))
    
    
                                
    
                                val tmp_df8 = tmp_df7.drop("id")
                                                       .drop("prec_c_bis")
                                                       .drop("prec_d_bis")
.drop("c_bis")
.drop("d_bis")
    
                                bigDf = bigDf.union(tmp_df8)

                            }

val index_D = index1.toDF("treated_paths")

val index_DF = index_D.union(index_hdfs)

index_DF.repartition(2).write.parquet("hdfs://****/Index2.parquet")

bigDf.repartition(3).write.parquet("hdfs://****/Group_csv.parquet")
```

Edit 2 (My stacktrace  when I am starting the write of parquet in hdfs ) :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
  at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:210)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:561)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
```

Edit 3 (Example of Data) :

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDSbj.png)

Edit 4 (GC overhead limit exceeded, when I lunsh my code on 10 000 files without `collect()` method )

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$FixNullability$$anonfun$apply$24$$anonfun$66.apply(Analyzer.scala:1849)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$FixNullability$$anonfun$apply$24$$anonfun$66.apply(Analyzer.scala:1844)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:221)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:428)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:428)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:428)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:428)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$FixNullability$$anonfun$apply$24.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1844)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$FixNullability$$anonfun$apply$24.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1841)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$FixNullability$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1841)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$FixNullability$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1839)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:50)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:67)
```

Comment: collect is an action.

Comment: @Hakim_93 as you now collect is an action and you are calling it on huge number of files you are tend to get the out of memory errors. You need to change your implementation way for this to get working.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya I try to lunsh my code without the collect on 10 000 files but I have `GC overhead limit exceeded` error (Edit 4). Can you tell me please what can I do to solve this problem and is it possible to automate this treatment ? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to creat a DF that contain all of you data and write it on HDFS when you can apply your transformations one file at a time? Apply your transformations on one file at time and after that if you what to reduce the number of output files create a spark job that will make file compactation.

Comment: Yes it's a possibility, but I need a user input arguments before lunsh my transphormations. Open a lot of CSVs, and make `collect()` each time is very slowly for the user, I think open few big file of parquet it's more speed and respect file compaction.

Comment: You don't understand how Spark it's work. Collect() method will transfer all data from your workers to driver and in your situation you want to avoid this.

Comment: I dont have other solution because I need use the data present at the first two columns in each csv. And this data are at the fourth row. You know a solution for use this data without use `collect()` method ?